# What does "/bin/sh" stand for in execlp command?

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, exec

I want to execute a shell command with execlp, I tried with the following instruction :

```
execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", p_command, (char*)NULL);
```

*p_command is a pointer to a `const char` representing a shell command line.*

My minimal test tells me the program succeded as expected. I first choose to use `"/bin/sh"` instead of `"sh"` but I've learned that *p*(*ath*) in `execlp` allows us to avoid writing the full path, as if exec will complete the path for us ; so I removed "/bin/".
My concern is that I never saw a code using execlp with only "sh", as it effectively does for exemple for ls we can directly use `"ls"` instead of `"/bin/ls"`.

As a beginner I am wondering what `"/bin/sh"` stands for, what is the difference between `"sh"` and `"/bin/sh"` in this situation and why we have to write the full path for `execlp` to execute a shell ?

Answer (score 1):

When the path passed to `execlp` is `sh`, `execlp` searches for it in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. If an attacker is able to modify the `PATH` variable in the environment that runs your program, they can set it to list a directory of their choosing, and they can place their own program named `sh` in that directory. Then your program will execute their program instead of executing the system `sh` program. In some cases (depending on a bit in the file’s mode bits), programs are executed with the permissions of their owners rather than the permissions of the user executing the program. Such programs must be written carefully to avoid situations like this, where an attacker would be able to exploit the program.

When the path passed to `execlp` is `/bin/sh`, `execlp` looks for it in the path that is `/bin/sh` starting from the root of the file system, called `/`. This will always use the `sh` program that the system administrator has put in the `/bin` directory (usually done as part of system installation).